# libmemcached-1.0.8 make fails in ubuntu lucid

Tags: ubuntu, memcached, libmemcached

I was trying to make and install `libmemcached-1.0.8` from source in ubuntu lucid.I tried these steps

```
sudo wget http://download.tangent.org/libmemcached-1.0.8.tar.gz
sudo ./configure -prefix=/usr
sudo make
```

the make command caused this error

```
In file included from memcached/assoc.c:14:
memcached/memcached.h:18:19: error: event.h: No such file or directory

    In file included from memcached/assoc.c:14:
    memcached/memcached.h:358: error: field ‘notify_event’ has incomplete type
    memcached/memcached.h:380: error: field ‘event’ has incomplete type
    make[1]: *** [memcached/memcached_memcached-assoc.o] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/libmemcached-1.0.8'
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I had installed memcached using

```
sudo apt-get install memcached
```

I tried to check where memcached is ,using `whereis memcached`
..It shows

```
memcached: /usr/bin/memcached /etc/memcached.conf /usr/include/memcached /usr/share/memcached /usr/share/man/man1/memcached.1.gz
```

can someone tell me what I should do to correctly make and install this library?

Edit:

as per the suggestion of @sarnold  ,I used

```
sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
```

and then

```
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Now ,there are 13 new executables starting with 'mem' in `/usr/bin` folder

Comment: .. why, specifically, are you trying to build your own if the distribution provides one for you already?

Comment: I need a recent version of libmemcached to install another software (pylibmc to be specific)  and found that existing version is quite old.When I import pylibmc to python ,I get `pylibmc requires >= libmemcached 0.32, was compiled with 0.31`

Comment: That's an excellent reason to compile from source, then. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`event.h` is probably provided by `libevent-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=event.h). Try `sudo apt-get install libevent-dev` and re-try your `./configure ; make` sequence.